# How to calculate the real SHA1 of a text?

Tags: postgresql, digest

As in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327289/287948) (see details there), I am using

```
SELECT encode(digest(x::text::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') FROM xtmp;
```

Not solved, is not the same hash tham original... Perhaps the `::text` enforced internal representation with `\n` symbols, so a solution will be direct cast to `bytea`, but it is an invalid cast.

The other workaround also not is a solution,

```
SELECT encode(digest( replace(x::text,'\n',E'\n')::bytea, 'sha1' ), 'hex') 
FROM xtmp
```

... I try `CREATE TABLE btmp (x bytea)` and `COPY btmp FROM '/tmp/test.xml' ( FORMAT binary )`, but error ("unknown COPY file signature").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution! Add a "\n".

```
SELECT encode(digest((x::text||E'\n')::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') FROM xtmp;
```

But the real problem is to get original file without cut the last "\n" (last EOL)... Lets see the function at [my old test-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327289/287948):

```
 INSERT INTO  xtmp (x) 
  SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(x),E'\n')::xml FROM ttmp
;
```

It is here the "bug" (after workaround the `COPY` that not load a full-file into one row one field).  
The   `array_to_string()` not adds the last EOL, so concatenating by `|| E'\n'` fixed the bug.

---

### NOTES

Checking other hypothesis and offering a good solution to the test-kit.

### POSIX rule is not the problem ...

The end-of-line (EOL) is an obligation at POSIX filesystems (and non-binary mode), see [this answer about EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/287948). We can imagine something like "string and file representations differ by an EOL"... We can check? it differs?

We can demonstrate by terminal that there are **no** "string *vs* file" problem, no strange addiction of EOL:

```
printf "<root/>" > original1.xml 
printf "<root/>\n" > original2.xml 
sha1sum original*.xml
printf "<root/>" | openssl sha1
printf "<root/>\n" | openssl sha1
```

results

```
062c3db8ce3458fc3ccaf2f930bf663d8ce31d7d  original1.xml
a05d91cbf0902b0fe341c979e9fc18fc69813f55  original2.xml
(stdin)= 062c3db8ce3458fc3ccaf2f930bf663d8ce31d7d
(stdin)= a05d91cbf0902b0fe341c979e9fc18fc69813f55
```

So `sha1sum` is not using an extra EOL, the string and the file are the some.

Now at SQL, the same conclusions:

```
SELECT encode(digest('<root/>'::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') ;
SELECT encode(digest(E'<root/>\n'::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') ;
```

results

```
 062c3db8ce3458fc3ccaf2f930bf663d8ce31d7d
 a05d91cbf0902b0fe341c979e9fc18fc69813f55
```

---

### Solution for a better test-kit

The `COPY` command is ugly for this simple *load/save text* procedure, lets use a direct getfile function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getfile(p_file text) RETURNS text AS $$
   with open(args[0],"r") as content_file:
       content = content_file.read()
   return content
$$ LANGUAGE PLpythonU;

SELECT encode(digest( getfile('/tmp/original1.xml') ::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') ;
SELECT encode(digest( getfile('/tmp/original2.xml') ::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') ;
```

results

```
062c3db8ce3458fc3ccaf2f930bf663d8ce31d7d
a05d91cbf0902b0fe341c979e9fc18fc69813f55
```

Perfect (!), no EOL problem now.