# SHA1 HASH of TEXT column - how to do in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hash, casting, sha1

I need a query that will encode a TEXT column w SHA1. It is not for passwords, but used as a simple changed status check. I truncate at 40chars as it is a loose check.

This query part works in **MS SQL SERVER**:

```
RIGHT( CONVERT([varchar](45), HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST(MY_XML as varchar(max))), 1) ,40) as HASH
```

A customer needs this to work in PostgreSQL.

I have looked at the `ENCODE`, `DIGEST` and other functions, but I can't seem to get the proper syntax.

These don't work:

```
DIGEST(CAST(MY_XML as varchar(max)),'SHA1')::varchar(40) as HASH
CAST(DIGEST(CAST(MY_XML as varchar),'SHA1') as varchar) as HASH
ENCODE(DIGEST(CAST(MY_XML as varchar(max)),'SHA1'),'hex') as HASH
ENCODE(DIGEST(MY_XML::text::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex') as HASH
```

(last one sourced from [How to calculate the real SHA1 of a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469225/how-to-calculate-the-real-sha1-of-a-text))

I feel I'm close, but as the saying goes..

Comment: If you're just using this as a check for a changed value, does it matter if it's SHA-1? Surely any consistent hash calculation would do?

Comment: Unfortunately it does as this is checking on a remote system and our application DB uses SHA1 validation on our end already

Comment: What does "don't work" mean?

Comment: 1) Define doesn't work. 2) For the examples you show you need to have the `pgcrypto` extension installed. Is that the case? 3) This `select encode(digest('this is test', 'sha1'), 'hex'); b6794b2000d94d348203d0279c2e7322b922cb16` works for me.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the need for the `pgcrypto` extension. I'll investigate this. thank you

Comment: FWIW, any SHA1 hash is exactly 40 hex digits by definition, there's no effect to truncate it.

Comment: I also tested on my local PostgreSQL 14 instance (homebrew on MacOS), I just had to `CREATE EXTENSION 'pgcrypto';` then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the crypto extension with

```
CREATE EXTENSION 'pgcrypto';
```

If you already have the field as text or varchar it's just:

```
encode(digest(MY_XML::bytea, 'sha1'), 'hex')
```