# PostgreSQL: Create function has error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I write the function, but it occurs error " ERROR: syntax error at or near "\""

I want to create file, But it does not seem to work.

How do I do it ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sqlDB (fileName VARCHAR)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  \i /tmp/fileName;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: `\i` is a  command specific to the `psql` it is not a [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) so you can not use it in a PL/pgSQL or SQL function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there no other way to create sql files in function?

Comment: I know its not on the tags but you can easily do that using a shell script.

Comment: plpythonu f.open(), f.write(), f.close()  Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812722/how-can-i-write-to-a-file-on-disk-from-pl-pgsql